# Add column with unique row value

Tags: sql, hierarchical-query

I have a table like this:

```
SELECT 
    parent_id,  
    parent2_id,   
    parent3_id,  
    parent4_id  
FROM 
    parents
```

[image]

I need to make it like this:

[image]

I need to add column with an unique value of a row, but since we have 4 columns, then there are four rows.
But, if anyone can make this result table without zero value in id column, it would be very cool.

upd: I found an answer, but it seems very large. Can the solution be simplified?

Comment: You need to repeat each column 4 times? And give each a unique ID? What are the zero IDs for?

Comment: You can do  it with a UNION or with a lateral join if your DBMS supports it.

Comment: If I understood the logic behind it besides the lack of explanation, OP wants the ID column to have one of each of the parent_id's except for the ones with 0 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
    parent_id as id,
    parent_id,  
    parent2_id,   
    parent3_id,  
    parent4_id  
FROM 
    parents
UNION ALL
SELECT parent2_id as id,
    parent_id,  
    parent2_id,   
    parent3_id,  
    parent4_id  
FROM 
    parents
UNION ALL
SELECT parent3_id as id,
    parent_id,  
    parent2_id,   
    parent3_id,  
    parent4_id  
FROM 
    parents
UNION ALL
SELECT parent4_id as id,
    parent_id,  
    parent2_id,   
    parent3_id,  
    parent4_id  
FROM 
    parents) as src
WHERE src.id != 0
```